# Add field on registration form for specific website

Tags: magento2

I created a custom module that add a field to the registration form and account modification.

The problem is that it is added to all websites. I only need it on a specific website.

This is the module I created:

https://github.com/stfn97/magento2-custom-registration-field

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add logic to a template (for example, render it only if certain "requirements" are met) you will use either a block or a view model.

In this case I recommend using a block because the `Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template` class contains a `_toHtml()` method which you can override to either render or not render your template.

```php
class MyBlockClass extends Template {
    public function _toHtml() {
        if (what you want your condition to be) {
            return '';
        }

        return parent::_toHtml();
    }
}
```

*you can use a ternary operator for this but I thought the above notation would be more obvious*

`Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface` can then be used to get the store the customer is currently in and thus the website as well.

If you call `Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface::getStore()` without an argument (store id) it will return the store the customer is currently in.

Because the above method returns a `Magento\Store\Api\Data\StoreInterface` the `Magento\Store\Api\Data\StoreInterface::getWebsiteId()` can then be used to get the website associated with the store the customer is currently in.

If you want more information about the website you'll need a `Magento\Store\Api\Data\WebsiteInterface`, this you can get by calling `Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface::getWebsite($websiteId)` with the website id returned by the previously mentioned method.

Combining all this you can determine the website the customer is currently in and use that to either render or not render the template using the `Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template::_toHtml()` method.